# Move cursor to specific cell when reading a specific barcode

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to figure out how to write a macro that would move the cursor to a specific row when a value of a specific barcode is written in any cell.

The barcodes will be a couple of numbers (1111 or something similar).

So lets say that i have written 5 id-numbers of a product into row A and i now want to write 5 id-numbers of another product into row B, in that case i have to walk all the way back to the computer and move a row to the right.

That is why i plan on having a paper with a list of barcodes for different products and when reading a barcode it would jump to that products row in excel. The file is always empty to begin with so the macro just needs to move to the top cell of the chosen row.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have a worksheet. The column A is filled with barcodes.

You enter some barcode into B1 cell. You want the cell in column A with the same code to be selected.

Use the below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo done
If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
    Range("A:A").Find(Target.Text).Activate
End If
done:
End Sub
```

Insert this code into this worksheet's module.